# Passing value from lightBox to parents

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

I am trying to create a profile screen for my user . It looks like this [image: Profile]

and the user can edit the information by clicking the TouchableOpacity and a lightbox from wix-react-native-navigation will pop up for the user to edit the info . It gonna looks like this

[image: Edit profile]

but how do i pass the textinput from lightbox to the parent ?

Answer (score -1):

Pass an onSave function with a signature of `onSave(name)` down to your dialog that is called when you hit save. Then, when the user triggers a save you can do something like `() => this.props.onSave(this.state.name)` to call the parent function with your textbox data. Does that make sense?